# enable user_birthday permission facebook birthday in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-profile

I m making a facebook app to display the birthday of a user.........

```
     <?
         require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
         $config = array(
                          'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
                          'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
                         );

         $facebook = new Facebook($config);
         $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
     ?>
     <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>

     <?
            if($user_id) 
            {

                  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
                  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
                  try 
                  {

                        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
                        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

                        // Birth Date to be printed here........
                       echo "DOB:  ".$user_profile['birthday'];
                  } 
                  catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
                  {
                       // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
                       // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
                      // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
                      // just ask the user to login again here.
                     $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
                     echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
                     error_log($e->getType());
                     error_log($e->getMessage());
                  }   
             } 
             else 
             {

                    // No user, print a link for the user to login
                    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
                    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

              }
     ?>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Now , the problem is `This prints the name as expected but prints nothing in place on date of birth`.......When i referred further, I heard  about the term facebook permissions (extended).....
and from the following link
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

I found that we need to enable permissions `users_birthday` or `friends_birthday`.

***Now, How do we enable it in php code ??***...Please help with samples.......
I m sorry if this question seems silly. I m just a new comer in facebook app developing and also a beginner in php.......
I tried the other examples in stackoverflow.com and it didn't help me much......

Comment: Just to elaborate a little extra on Igys answer below. When using Graph api. The very least by default that FB will ask for is the users basic information, and what falls under the basic information category, such as first and last name, member id, and so on. Anything else beyond that is either an extended information or a special permission to request for. Click the links in Igys answers to get a break down of the scopes and how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no indication you've read the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) or [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation; you're not asking the user for permission to access their birthday.

Add `user_birthday` to the `scope` when sending the user to the Auth Dialog and you'll be able to access their birthday if they approve the permissions.

The permissions you configure in the App Settings only apply to (deprecated) Authenticated Referrals or the App Center login screen, your app needs to explicitly ask for the permissions in all other login flows

Comment: i read it....but i don't understand how do we enable that permission and what is the php code to be included for that..???

Comment: I see no indication you've read his question; it is said "I found that we need to enable permissions users_birthday or friends_birthday.".

Comment: He seriously didn't read the documentation, which explains how to do this pretty clearly. My answer also tells him exactly what to do, which is add the 'user_birthday' scope to the auth dialog when he sends the user there. Also, this is a year old, the docs and examples have been updated since then several times

Comment: Your answer was fine, just that portion where you chastise is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask Facebook to approve your Application. After facebook review it, you are able to use Extended Permissions.

According with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#categories) Documentation, if your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends, it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers. [1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#categories)

I had the same issue than you. I thought it was wrong coded, everything. Then I just saw this on facebook v2.0 Documentation.